# How to truncate a database using sqllite in single command (Clear records from all the tables in database)

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am searching for bulk delete from all the tables from database.

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1,TABLE2,TABLE3; --(Is it possible)
```

like we have bulk insert

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

My code by which I am not satisfied as it is like this. It is able to do this.

```
Delete from table1;
Delete from table2;
Delete from table3;
```

---

```
public void truncateDatabase() {
    ArrayList<String> tables = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = Database.getInstance().getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            tables.add(cursor.getString(0));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();

    for (String table : tables) {
        Database.getInstance().getWritableDatabase().execSQL("DELETE FROM " + table);
        Database.getInstance().getWritableDatabase().execSQL("VACUUM");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html), a single DELETE statement works on a single table.

There's nothing wrong with executing multiple DELETE statements.

However, you should execute the VACUUM only once, and consider using a transaction:

```java
SQLiteDatabase db = Database.getInstance().getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    for (String table : tables) {
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + table);
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
db.execSQL("VACUUM");
```

Comment: I am using delete from table is there is a possibility of any command which can trunacate all the tables in database

Comment: Thanks for the help CL but how can my code is optimized as at is currently looping delete and vaccum. According to your suggestion>> (But you should execute the VACUUM only once, and consider using a transaction.) any example i will be extremely thankful to you